# VBA: Need to calculate time difference between times from different dates

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with calculating time difference between times from two different dates.

```
Cell(1,1) contains: 19/06/2016 01:00:00 
Cell(1,2) contains: 20/06/2016 02:30:00
```

The answer should be: 25:30:00
Following is my code:

```
Dim a As Date, b As Date    
a = Cells(1, 1).Value
b = Cells(1, 2).Value
Cells(1, 3).Value = TimeValue(b) - TimeValue(a)
```

But this code gives me 1:30:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate time difference in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475288/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-vba)

Comment: `TIMEVALUE` Function Returns the decimal number of the time represented by a text string. The decimal number is a value ranging from 0 (zero) to 0.99988426, representing the times from 0:00:00 (12:00:00 AM) to 23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.). As such your use of `TimeValue(b) - TimeValue(a)`is not correct. I think @Gary's Student solution is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

Just subtract:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim a As Date, b As Date
    a = Cells(1, 1).Value
    b = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Cells(1, 3).Value = b - a
    Cells(1, 3).NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

[image]